# Get array value by finding its key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Multidimensional array I am trying to search an element within the array by it's `key` and pull out it's `value`.

The array:

```
class MatchQuery{

    public $result;
    public $final;

    public function getStringAction($var){

        $this->result = array(
            array(
                'allUser' => 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user',
                'activeUser' => 'SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE status="1"',
                '' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'allTemplate' => 'SELECT * FROM tbl_template'
            )
        );

    }
}
```

Now lets say I call this class and function in another document, like so:

```
$string = new MatchQuery();
$string->getStringAction( 'allUser' );
```

as you can see the function needs one parameter `$var` so when I call this method in another file I give this parameter a name of one of they keys from the array.

How do I find that `key` and pull out the `value` only....?

Comment: How about using an array instead of a class?

Comment: Why are your arrays split up illogically?

Comment: A good article for you: https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: well the array is within a class is that bad...? @ialarmedalien what do you mean by illogically...?

Comment: Why is it a multi-dimensional array? Is there a significance to the different elements of the outer array?

Comment: Why have you got two sub-arrays and an empty key-value pair? Why not just have a single associative array?

Comment: yep perhaps I could remove the sub array, can agree on this one, I just though I could cattegorise the elements within the array by adding sub arrays, Now lets say I remove these sub arrays How do I then search the array by key and pull out the key value only...?

Comment: `$array[$var]` is how you access an array element by its key. Are you looking for something other than that?

Comment: @Barmar ok and the result of that will be the array key value only...?

Comment: Yes, what else would it be? This is basic PHP syntax.

Comment: @Tomazi Ismael linked you to the article. It explains everything you need to adjust the array.

Comment: But do I have to do this in a loop e.g foreach....to go through each key...?

Comment: Thank you all for your help this has worrked for me @Barmar, $this->result[$var], Ofcourse I removed all the sub arrays and made just one array :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach and try this

```
public function getStringAction($var){
    $this->result = array(
        array(
            'allUser' => 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user',
            'activeUser' => 'SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE status="1"',
            '' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'allTemplate' => 'SELECT * FROM tbl_template'
        )
    );
    if($var){
        foreach($this->result as $key=>$value){
            if($key == $var){
                return $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```